# attribute insetForeground has already be defined

Tags: android, android-support-library

after updating to the new

```
com.android.support:design:22.2.0
```

I got this error:

> "attribute insetForeground has already be defined"

keep in mind that i'm using @romannurik [ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

just change

```
insetForeground attribute
```

in your `attrs.xml` to a different name

Answer (score 10):

To elaborate on Omar's answer,

The Android design support library introduced NavigationDrawer that is used together with DrawerLayout to provide means of implementing navigation etc. See here:

[Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

The NavigationDrawer extends ScrimInsetsFrameLayout which was brought into the library.

The error in the question occurs because the insetForeground attribute was defined twice.
Once is the context of the library and once when a copy of ScrimInsetsFrameLayout was brought into the project.

Options:

1. Rename the property defined in the project (as suggested by Omar)
   while continuing using the local copy of ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.
2. Remove the local copy of ScrimInsetsFrameLayout and use the one in the
   library instead.
3. Remove the local copy of ScrimInsetsFrameLayout and use
   NavigationDrawer instead.

Answer (score 7):

You have this class `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java` in your files whereas Google already put this in the Google Android Support Design Library. Replace the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` into `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

Comment: Is that the same thing as `insetForeground`?

Answer (score 0):

Or else you can rename **insetForeground** in your **values/attr.xml** to **insetForeground2** or something